# get_threshold() use other than grabage collection

Tags: python, list, file, csv, threshold

`get_threshold()` as given in python document is an object of garbage collection. But is it possible to use the same object to identify the threshold in the list or more simple any CSV?

Comment: What do you mean for *threshold of a list*? the max?

Comment: @enrico.bacis Yes may be the max value in the list with collection of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`get_threshold`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_threshold) from module [`gc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) deals with the garbage collection, the mechanism that removes the objects which are not referenced anymore. Read more about garbage collector thresholds [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold).

If you want to get the maximum of a list, you can just use the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function:

```
>>> lst = [5, 3, 7, 1, 6, 5, 2]
>>> print max(lst)
7
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but `get_threshold` is an arcane detail of CPython's memory management implementation, and isn't useful for any other task.

Comment: I want to find a the threshold value in a list of data file or array of data.